# why are useState,useEffect imported in {} in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**why are useState,useEffect imported in {} in React.**

import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';

Comment: because they are exported as named properties, not as default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not react related. This is standard javascript.

Suppose we have this file:

React.js

```
export const useState = (initialState) => {
    // the useState code here
};

export const useEffect = (handler, dependencies) => {
    // the useEffect code here
};

const React = {
    useState,
    useEffect,
    // other functions here maybe
};

export default React;
```

> Please note this is a simple example.

When importing, javascript sees two things:

1 - Named properties (variables marked with `export`)

2 - Default export - single variable or function that is exported. in this case, an object containing the two functions above

Named properties are imported using `{}`, while the default export does not use `{}`

With this example implementation you could use like this:

```
import React, { useState } from './React.js';

// use the property exported
const [state1, setState1] = useState(1);
// access property from default export
const [state2, setState2] = React.useState(2);
```